# Accept 2 strings with same length using turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

This problem is asked in NET exam.

can you please tell me how to solve this problem. Problem is accept two string with same length.

I wnat answer in {turing machine table like q0==> [q0,b,a] } this format.

shubhadaa

Comment: It will be really interesting to see if someone goes down to that level here :-). Turing machines - I always imagined them steam powered, ejecting great billows of smoke and steam while performing their tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an exam is show that you can devise an algorithm and express it in Turing's notation, so giving you the machine table would be counter productive.  Assuming, however, both strings are encoded on the same tape, a simple character marking algorithm should suffice.